# rails controller index render validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make it work?

books_controller.rb:

1)

```
def index
  @books = Book.where(library_id.present?)
end
```

2)

```
def warsaw_books
  @books = Book.where(city == 'Warsaw')
end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Finding records where `library_id` is not nil:

```
def index
  @books = Book.where.not(library_id: nil)
end
```

2) Finding records where `city` is `'Warsaw'`:

```
def warsaw_books
  @books = Book.where(city: 'Warsaw')
end
```